# Add an element to page. Than drag it

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I'm adding an element on a page but i can't drag it. Can anyone help me out with this.This is my code:

Html

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="button" value="clickme" id="clickme">
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css

```
#dragme {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And JavaScript with jQuery

```
 $("#clickme").click(function() {
    $(".mainDiv").append("<div id='dragme'>Drag me</div>");
  });

  $("#dragme").draggable();
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tpdx1e83/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $.draggable is a method from jQuery UI package, so if you want to use it, you will have to include it.

Secondly, when you call `$("#dragme").draggable()`, the element is not added to the DOM yet and therefore `$("#dragme")` will return nothing. You will have to call this function after you add the #dragme element in the page.

Here is a working update of your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/tpdx1e83/1/